# SNAT/Masquerade not modifying the Source IP occasionally

Tags: iptables, nat

We do SNAT in our Gateway in the POSTROUTING chain. But we find that once in a while the source IP did not get modified. The packet is going out with the internal IP.
We are using IP Tables version - 1.6.2
Linux Kernel version - 4.14.78

Following is the output of `iptables-save -c`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Apr 2 14:48:00 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4063:381303]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2441:203832]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2871:229200]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [226:16504]
[3608:318784] -A POSTROUTING -o wwan0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Apr 2 14:48:00 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Apr 2 14:48:00 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [23264:3684627]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [164478:152807892]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [53990:65694281]
[483:68408] -A INPUT -i lan3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
[447:23510] -A FORWARD -i wwan0 -o lan1 -j DROP
[543:31927] -A FORWARD -i wwan0 -o lan2 -j DROP
[35:2083] -A FORWARD -i wwan0 -o lan3 -j DROP
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i wwan0 -o lan4 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Apr 2 14:48:00 2021
```

`wwan0` is the default gateway.

How to fix this problem?

Snapshot of TCP Dump. The internal IP's (172.16..) are highlighted. The translated IP is `100.86.203.169`. We can find several NAT happening correctly. Once in 10 to 15 minutes we find few entries of source IP not translated. There are earlier transactions to the same IP for which the IP translations were correct.

```
17:13:51.939700 IP 100.86.203.169.47554 > 135.sub-198-224-172.myvzw.com.domain: 64282+ AAAA? connectivitycheck.gstatic.com. (47)
17:13:52.033482 IP 135.sub-198-224-172.myvzw.com.domain > 100.86.203.169.47554: 63258 1/0/0 A 172.217.11.163 (63)
17:13:52.033598 IP 100.86.203.169.hostmon > 224.0.0.252.hostmon: UDP, length 27
17:13:52.042355 IP 135.sub-198-224-172.myvzw.com.domain > 100.86.203.169.47554: 64282 1/0/0 AAAA 2607:f8b0:4007:804::2003 (75)
17:13:52.043389 IP 100.86.203.169 > lax28s15-in-f3.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 34628, seq 0, length 64
17:13:52.132848 IP lax28s15-in-f3.1e100.net > 100.86.203.169: ICMP echo reply, id 34628, seq 0, length 64
17:13:52.237290 IP **172.16.9.59.63478** > lax31s14-in-f14.1e100.net.443: UDP, length 1350
17:13:52.366892 IP 100.86.203.169.hostmon > 224.0.0.252.hostmon: UDP, length 27
17:13:52.416431 IP **172.16.9.68.45839** > lax17s14-in-f14.1e100.net.https: Flags [F.], seq 1838160668, ack 751548505, win 373, options [nop,nop,TS val 31214649 ecr 2926508259], length 0
17:13:52.419421 IP **172.16.9.68.45840** > lax17s14-in-f14.1e100.net.https: Flags [F.], seq 3938547017, ack 4273274368, win 373, options [nop,nop,TS
```

Comment: do you have specific rules for the host  lax31s14-in-f14.1e100.net or for UDP somewhere else?

Comment: you should dump your whole ruleset eg: `iptables-save -c`. As Timmy Browne suggests, the problem could be in an other part

Comment: Added the dump of iptables-save -c

Comment: Can't find a reason with what you have. There are probably many other possible cause. conntrack entries overflooded, some race bug that would still be on old kernels (what's the kernel version?). If it's easy for you to reproduce it (15mn), you might have to keep a `conntrack -E -o timestamp` redirected to a log file at the same time you're running tcpdump and then attempt to compare between both what happens when the non-NATed packets are seen.